# Adding global classes member pointers to std::list in constructor, causes trouble on next class add

Tags: c++, list, class, std

I'm developing quite large project for NodeMCU controller using C++ Arduino api. 
(using VS Code Platformio for compiling and running)

My project contains some modules done as classes with only one member created using `extern`

```
//LedModule.h
extern _LedModule LedModule;

//LedModule.cpp
_LedModule LedModule;
```

I had created Abstract base class, from which i extended other classes

```
class IParameter {
public:
    virtual void initParameter();
};
```

so... in LedModule.h

```
class _LedModule : public IParameter {
  //...
  void initParameter();
  //...
};
```

I used `std::list<IParameter *> registredParameters;` to save all modules that use interface
so in LedModule.cpp

```
_LedModule::_LedModule(){
  //..
  registredParameter.push_back(this);
  //..
};
```

After this I utilise this list on runtime by calling interface function

All worked fine, but on next module added, controller resets on load.

By (I can't debug controller realtime) commenting block

```
//registredParameter.push_back(this);
```

I realise that controller fails on adding new pointer to list, because list constructor was not called when my module constructor called

due to [In what order are global constructors called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222743/in-what-order-are-global-constructors-called)

in C++ you can't know in which order constructors called if you are using multiple transaction units

**How to safely add global class member pointer to list?**

*I don't actually want to create large function and manually gather classes to add to this list;*

Comment: Does this help? http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html

Comment: @parktomatomi thank you, this helped a lot, can you add an answer, i will mark it as correct